# Ошибка при монтировании удаленной фс: "mount: wrong fs type, bad option"

Tags: linux, shell, mount

Пытаюсь монтировать удаленную файловую систему:

```
sudo mount -t cifs "//some.url/path" '~/local.path' -o  
    username=$(whoami),rw,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,noperm
```

Получаю ошибку с довольно неопределенным комментарием. В чем проблема, как монтировать?

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on some.url/path, missing codepage or helper program, or other error (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount. helper program)
>   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

В данном случае релевантна та часть сообщения об ошибке, которая говорит об утилите, необходимой для работы с файловой системой *cifs*:

> for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount. helper program

Для монтирования требуемой файловой системы, например cifs или nfs, необходимо установить соответствующие утилиты.

Проверить возможность работы:

```
ls -l /sbin/mount.cifs
ls -l /sbin/mount.nfs
```

Установлен ли пакет:

```
dpkg -l cifs-utils
dpkg -l nfs-common
```

Установить (пример для Debian/Ubuntu, аналогичные пакеты есть для других пакетных менеджеров):

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

Comment: хм. а *nfs*-то тут при чём? эта файловая система лишь для примера в сообщении об ошибке упомянута.

Comment: Спасибо! проверка установленных пакетов показала что нет cifs-utils. Доставил пакет и все заработало.

Comment: @user200907: хорошо, что вам помог ответ. Тут формат сайта отличается от обычных форумов — в качестве «спасибо» можно проголосовать за ответ. Новый ответ для этого не подходит, так что я его преобразовал в комментарий.